# c:\windows\installer contains hundreds of .msi with same date and time using most of my space

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2019

My Windows Server 2019 is out of space and after researching I found out that the c:\windows\installer folder is using over 200GB, that's not normal because all other files are only around 24GB.

what's more weird is that there are hundreds and hundreds of msi files all named differently but all have the same size, date and timestamp. they are only about 129MB each but all together are filling up my hard drive.

My question is, would it be safe to delete these files? I have been unable to find any more information about these files from the event logs for that date and time.

Comment: `would it be safe to delete these files?` Ouija says: Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the msi files in the folder are 129MB. In your case this could be caused by any software installed on the server.
To detect this, you need to right click on the header and enable Authors. This way you can see which software these msi files belong to.

[image]